# UnicodeDecodeError when using XGBoost or Shap

Tags: python, python-3.8

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe8 in position 34: invalid continuation byte

Has anyone come across an error when working with XGBoost and SHAP ? Forget position number of the error.
I have tried a number of things like downgrading XGBoost version to 1.1.0 and SHAP to 0.35.0, added encoding='ISO-8859-1', encoding='latin-1' or encoding='utf8' with errors='ignore' when importing/loading the dataframe (CSV file) but no luck.

Comment: Are you using categorical features?

Comment: @yatu, Categorical and numerical

Comment: Categorical values are not supported. Use numerical values

Comment: I have confirmed the variables, they are all numerical

Comment: @Yatu, i meant the all the variables have numerical values

Comment: But are they really numerical? Check the dtypes

Comment: @Yatu, i created a bucket which is about  player position. It is categorical !!

Comment: I found away around it. I had to do the following;

Comment: Check the encoding of the CSV file using import chardet library. And my encoding turned out to be "UTF-8-SIG" but mere specification of the encoding was not sufficient to solve the problem. An additional argument of engine = "python" did the magic.